# Generating 2 bars water pressure with weight

Tags: pressure

I am trying to build an irrigation system without electricity. I am aiming for 2 bars pressure in the pipes. Is there a way to create pressure in the water tank using weight and how much weight would I need to create the desired pressure in a 1x1 meter water tank?

Or perhaps I better be using a lower diameter to reduce the weight?

My initial calculations showed 2 tons for 1x1 meter water tank, that can't be right, right? ;-)

Comment: Or have your be tank 64  feet (19.5 meters) in the air.

Comment: Tip 1, always work in S.I. units and convert at the end, this keeps calculations clean and mitigates chances of calculation errors. 
Tip 2, as mentioned by zeta-band, water/liquid with a density creates a pressure depending on the height due to gravity $P=\rho \cdot g \cdot h$. 
Tip 3, make an inventory of what you have available.
Tip 4,  write down the most important characteristics you want in the system.
Once you have that and if you mention it, it might be easier to help as well.

Comment: 2 bars = 20394.32 $kg/m^2$ ; a metric tonne is 1000kg

Comment: Like zeta-band said, why not just lift the water tank into the air? That's what I've seen done with water tanker trucks at a work site when they want apparently want to increase the water pressure at the outlet of the water hose. They simply raise the water tank with large jacks and, voila! They have more water pressure. Sure is simpler than putting heavy weights on the water.

Comment: You can use a hand pump to pressurise a sealed tank at ground level. Or you could power it with any pressure or p.e. existing in your supply. It would just use that power source instead of electricity.

Comment: @BobvandeVoort thank you for the tips, I will try S.I. Regarding height, I am building this in my flat in order to water dozens of plants so I only have 3 meters to play with. The main characteristics was to try to do it with gravity, not  for saving money but just as an experiment. It might be that a pump is my only way. So far I have put 20 meters of 4mm PVC tube with 6 exits. It only dripped in two locations (which was quite exciting as a first sign of water movement). The water tank is on a chair on the fridge around 2.20m in the air which gives 1-2m height distance to plants.

Comment: 2 bars are required in order to use drippers.

Comment: Fully automatic is a bit tricky and 2 meters only give you about 0.2 bar. So you still need another 1.8 bar. Keep in mind you might also lose pressure due to flow losses (if that happens get a slightly bigger pvc pipe). I suggest make the tank as narrow as possible, less area, this means you need less weight. Otherwise I suggest a compressor maybe. Like you'll need a cheap solar panel, cheap compressor, something akin to an arduino and a pressure sensor, total cost probably around 30 bucks or so from aliexpress. This will pressurize the systems once it falls below a set value.

Comment: I forgot to mention, you also need a chargeable battery to store the electricity.

Comment: Use electricity and a centrifugal pump, and save yourself a whole LOT of headaches!

Comment: @zeta-band, if the OP had a water source that could get water into a tank located 19.5 meters above grade, his problem would be solved by using this water source to directly run his irrigation system.